# Angular RxJs - fill array in the second stream (nested stream)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have in my Angular application a list of a specific model. Each item of this list has a propery `xyzList`. This `xyzList` property should be filled from a request which depends on the id of the first request. Here an example:

**Model**:

```
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  xyzList: any[]
}
```

Now I have two requests:

**Request 1**: Fills the model, but not the `xyzList`

`this.myVar$ = this.myService.getElements<Model[]>();`

**Request 2**: Should fill `xyzList`

`this.myService.getXyzElements<XyzModel[]>(idOfTheModelOfTheFirstRequest);`

At first I thought something like that:

```
this.myService.getElements<Model[]>()
.pipe(
  mergeMap(items => items)
  mergeMap(item => {
    return this.myService.getXyzElements<XyzModel[]>(item.id)
           .pipe(
             map(xyzList => {
               item.xyzList = xyzList

               return item;
             })
           )
  })
)
```

This does not work as I have flattened my list and I need an `Observable<Array[]>`, but I think is more or less clear what I want to achieve. I assume I can achieve this with `forkJoin` for instance, but I don't know how.Or is there a way to convert the flattened list back to list?

Comment: Try to add `toArray()` as last operator of the pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use toArray(), because mergeMap/flatMap is used to flatten the array of data stream. It will return an Array instead of data steam.

```
this.myService.getElements<Model[]>()
.pipe(
  mergeMap(items => items)
  mergeMap(item => {
    return this.myService.getXyzElements<XyzModel[]>(item.id)
           .pipe(
             map(xyzList => {
               item.xyzList = xyzList

               return item;
             })
           )
  }),
  toArray()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand that you have a service function that return a list of "items". EachItem you need call another service function that return the data "xyzList".

So, each "item" must be a call, then, you create an array of "calls"

```
    myService.getElements().pipe(
        switchMap(result=>{
          //We can not return the "list"
          let calls:Observable[]=[]
            //Before, the first calls was the own result
            calls.push(of(result));
            //Each result push the calls
            result.forEach(e=>{
                calls.push(myService.getXyzElements(e.id));
            })

            return forkJoin(calls).pipe(map(result=>{
               //in result[0] we have the list of items
               //In result[1] we have the Xyz of items[0]
               //In result[2] we have the Xyz of items[1]
               int i:number=0;
               result[0].map(x=>{
                  i++;
                  return {
                      ...x,
                      xyzList:result[i]
                  }
               })
               return result[0];
            }))
        })
    ).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
```